# Mobile to main redirect loop coming only for android browsers

Tags: php, android, redirect

I have an issue for my mobile website, i have a domain as xyz.com and a subdomain for mobile as m.xyz.com. I have handled the server redirect(from mobile to main website) logic through session handling(php default) and not with cookie.

The problem I am experiencing is that the returning user(only android phones) keeps on redirecting from m.xyz.com to xyz.com and back. For all other Windows phone, Iphone the site keeps working fine. What to do now !

Please help!

Comment: First off, if you are using (default) PHP sessions, then you are also using a cookie. Second, you have to be aware, that redirecting based on user agent strings are inherently unreliable. Then you'll need to show some code, on how you are actually. Finally there is probably some configuration you aren't aware of (and thus wont post), that does the reverse redirect.